# Suntour xctV2 appaeared to be locked in place and have no movement at all

Tags: fork, suspension

I'm new to suspension on bike and if I put all my weight down on the suspension it doesn't go down?

It's a used Specialized Hardrock. Only paid £230 for it. All other parts brand new, literally everything. But there isn't any movement in the suspension at all. I can turn the lock one about half a turn then it starts to get hard to push it.

Also it may have been left outside so could be stuck?

Comment: Is it a new fork? Used? Has it been stored or not used for a while? Did it work yesterday? Also - don't just "put all your weight down." Squeeze the front brake while you are doing it.

Comment: Is this a fork with lockout? If it is, did you turn off the lockout?